# win32 notification Abt child control creation

Tags: winapi

So I am creating an button with the CreateWindowEx() function with it's parent(some value) in the parent WM_CREATE message handler part with it's own user data i.e the very last parameter of CreateWindowEx() is an pointer to some arbitrary data.

When an root/main window is created  we receive an 
WM_CREATE or WM_NCCREATE message which allows us to Access this date with an CREATESTRUCT via the LPARAM value and assign it to the window via the SetWindowPtr(user data)

But when an child control is created and attached to this parent the parent window procedure doesn't receive the WM_CREATE message and the creation data for this button
Passed into the CreateWindowEx () is lost

Is there a way to know when an child control has been successfully created(or ready to be displayed) in this parent in the parent window procedure so I can fulfill the above task?

Basically I want to create an heirarchy of controls (like in Java with panels and panes) with the parent creating it's children when it receives it's WM_CREATE(or some other message just to know when I can start assigning children to it)and those children in turn creating their own children when it receives their WM_CREATE messages and so own.

Comment: The window procedure for the button class is provided by the OS (user32.dll), so that is where the `WM_CREATE` gets sent.  You should only use `SetWindowPtr` on windows of a class type you registered.  But you don't have a problem here, you know creation of your child control has completed when `CreateWindowEx` returns.

Comment: You *can* receive `WM_CREATE` for child windows, by using subclassing, if that is what you want (using `GetClassInfo()` / `RegisterClass()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parent window receives a WM_PARENTNOTIFY for child window creation (and a few other events). Be sure not to set the WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY extended style (which is set by default for controls created by the dialog window class).

The data received as part of the WM_PARENTNOTIFY upon window creation includes the LPCREATESTRUCT that was sent to the window during WM_NCCREATE/WM_CREATE (WM_PARENTNOTIFY occurs only if the window was successfully created).

Comment: Yes this suits my purpose perfectly. But what if the depth of my parent child heirarchy increases i.e lets say parent-->child-->grandchild-->greatgrandchild? After parent receives child PARENT NOTIFY I assign grandchild to child but then I will need to listen for grandchild PARENTNOTIFY in parent to assign great grandchild to it. Will grandchild PARENTNOTIFY reach the parent procedure? . In general will this work flow work for any depth of an component tree?

Comment: And as for subclassing and registering my own class it works perfectly but the extra work tends to become messy

Comment: Regarding changing where in the window tree a particular child is created, from the WM_PARENTNOTIFY docs: This message is also sent to all ancestor windows of the child window, including the top-level window.